# Ошибка z-index

Tags: html, css

При наведении на пункт подменю "О предприятии" подменю должно быть позади.
Свойства css установил как нужно.

Коды: http://jsfiddle.net/rmLS7/

**Обновлено:**

Ещё проблема - не применяются стили

```
.submenu li a{
    font: 20px "Myriad Pro";
    color: #417f81;
}
```

к подменю.

Помогите исправить.

Comment: Тут нужно так писать

    #main_menu .submenu li a{
        font: 20px "Myriad Pro";
        color: #417f81;
    }

Т.е. добавить id перед селектором

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте к #main_menu li a свойства position и z-index

```
#main_menu li a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо так,наверно,Ваш код

```
<ul class="submenu">
 <li><a href="">История</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Технологии</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Достижения</a></li>
 <li><a href="">Продукция</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Значит css

```
ul.submenu li a {
font: 20px "Myriad Pro";
color: #417f81;
}
```

Так ,наверно)

Если нет,то вот ,прям ваш пример

[меню тут](http://jemand.ru/gorizontalnoe-vypadayushhee-menyu-na-css/)

Comment: нет, это неправльно